# No Wifi Adapter Found Error Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows and everything works fine except for that my Wifi randomly stopped working in Ubuntu. It was working one minute and then disappeared. It has been a few days sense I completed the install. I checked the BIOS settings to make sure secure boot was off and the WLAN capabilities are enabled. I can tether to my phone and use ethernet just fine, but no wifi. When I go into settings and look for Wifi it tells me no Wifi adapter is found. I have tried doing all the system updates and tried various solutions from various forums that have done nothing. Can anyone help me figure this out. I don't think it is a physical hardware issue because it was working perfectly fine one moment and then not the next and the computer hasn't been touched.

```
vm@vm:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] (rev c4)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15b3
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Platform Security Processor
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Audio Dummy Host Bridge
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 4b)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4b)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney HT Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney Address Maps
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney DRAM Configuration
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney Miscellaneous Configuration
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney PM Configuration
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney NB Performance Monitor
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
vm@vm:~$ ^C
vm@vm:~$ 




 vm@vm:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
    01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.          RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```

Comment: You have to tell us what kind of WiFi chip you have. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1305557/edit) and add the new information.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @user68186 how do i find that out? I think its a Realtek brand but I'm not sure where to find the information of the exact model.

Comment: Copy and paste the command @Pilot6 has put in his comments above and then paste the output [back in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1305557/edit). Finally format the pasted output in the question `as code` by using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Comment: @Pilot6 When I try to type that command into the terminal it doesn't give me an output. Just takes me back to the command prompt....

Comment: Are you using a USB adapter?

Comment: @Pilot6 no I am not. The only things plugged into the PC is the HDMI cable, keyboard, and mouse.

Comment: What does `lspci` show then? Is it a desktop? Desktops rarely have Wi-Fi.

Comment: It doesn't show anything. Ive been using this PC with wifi for windows and it was working fine with Ubuntu until I updated the system. @Pilot6

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't show anything"? Please run `lspci` in a terminal and post the output to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 Sorry it took me so long but I ran the lspci command and pasted the output to my question. Honestly though I have no idea what I'm looking for

Comment: Now please run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`, and don't tell me that  it shows nothing. Copy it carefully. And formatting doesn't mean to  add `{` symbols, but to click the `{}` icon above the text.

Comment: @Pilot6 Ok I posted the output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment because I'm don't have 50 reputation. I was having a similar issue as Masha. The issue began when my system was updated to linux kernel 5.8. When I booted to linux kernel 5.4 there were no WIFI problems.

Masha can you show the output of the following command: `uname -r`

If your output displays something like **5.8**.0-58-generic.

Try rebooting the PC and when you are on GRUB go to "advance ubuntu options for ubuntu" press enter and there will be 2 options:

Ubuntu, with linux kernel 5.4

Ubuntu, with linux kernel 5.8

Select Ubuntu, with linux kernel 5.4, press enter, once the OS boots up check if your WIFI problems persist.