# Network unavailable when resume from suspend after updating Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, suspend

After a recent update of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS when I resume my laptop from suspend my WIFI does not work. WIFI does work after rebooting the laptop.

Here is what I have tried.

sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

sudo service network-manager restart

sudo nmcli networking off

sudo nmcli networking on

Non of these worked. There were no problems before the update and restoring to a previous state with timeshift resolves the problem. Here are the outputs of some commands that my help.

**sudo lshw -C network**

-network DISABLED

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 24
   serial: c4:85:08:43:dc:6c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-34-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 6000g2b-6.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:31 memory:f1500000-f1501fff
```

-network

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 06
   serial: e8:03:9a:e8:1a:51
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-34-generic firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
   resources: irq:19 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1404000-f1404fff memory:f1400000-f1403fff
```

**nmcli device**

DEVICE             TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION

30:D9:D9:28:09:E4  bt        disconnected  --

enp3s0             ethernet  unavailable   --

wlp2s0             wifi      unavailable   --

lo                 loopback  unmanaged     --

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list**

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)

```
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4060]

Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

0: phy0: Wireless LAN

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

2: hci0: Bluetooth

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

**rfkill**

ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD

0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked

2 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked

**EDIT: the problem occur with Linux kernel 5.8 but no with Linux kernel 5.4**

Comment: Report it as a bug.

Comment: Don't know if this is still your issue, but chances are that your `lo` device has lost it's address, and therefore dnsmasq and your routes are completely broken. I have been trying to figure out a way to fix it automatically but if you run `ip link set lo down` followed by `ip link set lo up` it gets its address back and things start working again. That's what I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the first thing you should check is if your wireless interface is going into powersave mode maybe? So maybe first try to configure powermanagement referencing this KBA: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power.html.en if you hadn't done so before.

Wireless powersaving can be changed like this:

Create a file in /etc/pm/config.d named blacklist

```
gksu gedit /etc/pm/config.d/blacklist
```

and inside the file keep:

```
HOOK_BLACKLIST="wireless"
```

If you want to disable any other hooks, default hooks are located at /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/.

Per this KBA:[How can I prevent iwconfig power management from being turned on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on)

It has some alternative ways to achieve the same thing in this post.

Hope that fixes it for you.
you might have to reboot after these changes.

Comment: Tried that and it did not work. 

I've found another thread with a similar problem but I don't know if the cause of the problems is related or not. 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305557/no-wifi-adapter-found-error-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Try toubleshooting wifi card drivers, see which one you are using and see if there is another 'non-recommended' one you could try?

Comment: It is a laptop I think it is not possible to swap WIFI cards. The problems persists on linux kernel 5.8 but if I boot to linux kernel 5.4 the WIFI is working perfectly. Any ideas on how to upgrade to linux kernel 5.8 and still have WIFI?

Comment: Hi, I meant trying another wifi driver, not another wifi card. There are possibly different driver versions for your card. Try that.